# Senha-Mestra com PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como criar uma senha-mestra em PHP a qual possa ser utilizada para garantir acesso a um determinado recurso protegido por autenticação, independente do usuário informado.

Comment: Você já pensou em adicionar um if dizendo que se o usuario e senha digitados foram x  e y então é pra logar sem checar?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo (requisito/motivo), o que você já tentou e que dificuldades encontrou? Adianto uma sugestão: não faça isso.

Comment: Seria interessante saber os motivos. Mas concordo com o @Caffé, não faca isso, e uma péssima ideia em termos de segurança.

Comment: Reescrevi a redação do tópico. Agora pode até ser que se justifique sua reabertura, apesar de eu concordar com as avaliações negativas.

Comment: Sugiro não misturar **autenticação** com **autorização**: normalmente quando um usuário está autenticado ("logado") ele está automaticamente autorizado a executar as ações a que ele tem direito (i.e. de acordo com seu grupo e/ou permissões). Mas nada impede que você *estenda* sua autorização através de um comando especial (pense no `sudo` por exemplo). E se achar interessante manter essa autorização estendida por mais tempo, guarde em uma variável de sessão se o usuário X entrou ou não com essa "senha mestra", e se entrou, *autorize-o* a acessar tal recurso enquanto durar a sessão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode criar um campo na tabela com o nome `senhamestre` e quando for a hora de realizar a condicional para a senha, faça um `OR` para `senhamestre`. Assim poderá se *logar* com o valor senha ou com a senha mestre.